# Сгенерировать перестановки транспозицией соседних элементов

Tags: c++, алгоритм, циклы

Пусть дана перестановка `{1,2,3,4,5}`. Можно ли в цикле сгенерировать все `n!` перестановок, меняя местами только соседние элементы?

Comment: в библиотеке `algorithm` есть готовый алгоритм `std::next_permutation` с помощью которого можно получить все `n!` перестановок.

Comment: @uber42,  а вы покажите как с помощью этого альгоритма переставить только соседные элементы

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, вопрос не в том как переставить соседние элементы, а в том можно ли такими образом получить все перестановки, я лишь предложил свой вариант ...

Answer (score 0):

Да, можно, для этого есть алгоритм **Джонсона-Троттера**. [Вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Trotter_algorithm)

Comment: Является. Это прямой ответ на заданный вопрос.